# Dynamic page fetching with AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i have a question regarding partial page loading with AJAX.

Suppose that an user clicks on a button that makes an AJAX call to load part of a page (it can possibly include dynamically loaded JS and/or CSS), and the html content is dropped on some div. Then, before the first load is complete he clicks on another button that makes another AJAX call that drops other content on the same div. How should i prevent this behaviour to create any conflicts? Some possible conflicts might be something like, for example, the first load executes some JS on content that is not found because the second load already changed that div.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I would appreciate answers based on asynchronous methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this would actually be a problem for you because Javascript is single threaded.  When the first ajax response comes in and you execute some javascript, that javascript cannot be interupted by the second ajax response as long as it is one continuous thread of execution (no timers or other asynchronous ajax calls as part of it's processing).

Let's run through a scenario:

1. User clicks button - first ajax call starts.
2. User clicks button - second ajax call starts.
3. First ajax call finishes and the completion code execution starts for what to do with the new data.
4. While code is executing from first ajax call, the second ajax call completes.  At this point, the browser puts the second ajax call completion into a queue.  It cannot trigger any of your completion code yet because the Javascript engine is still running from the first load.
5. Now the first load completes it's execution and code and returns from it's completion handler.
6. The browser now goes to it's queue and finds the next event to process.  It finds the completion of the second ajax call and then starts the completion code for that ajax call.

As you can see from this scenario which has overlapping ajax calls and the second completing in the middle of the processing the first, there still is no conflict because the Javascript engine is single threaded.

Now, as the other answers have suggested, you make not want this user experience of launching a new request while one is still processing, but they won't technically conflict with each other.  You have several tools you can choose from if you want to prevent overlapping calls:

- You can prevent starting the second call while the first call is unfinished.  You can do this both in the UI and in the actual code.
- When there are multiple calls outstanding, you can decide to drop/ignore the earlier responses and not process them - waiting only for the last response.
- When the second call is initiated, you can cancel the first call.
- You can let the second just replace the first as in the above scenario.

The first two options require you to keep track of some cross ajax-call state so one ajax call can know whether there are others and act accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Well, if i got your answer, you're saying that the second asynchronous AJAX call will load asynchronously, but it will _only_ execute after the first request was executed right?

Comment: Whichever ajax call completes first will execute first.  Once it starts to execute, it won't be interrupted by the other one as long as it's one continuous thread of execution (no timers or other asynchronous calls).  If the second call completes before the first one does, it will execute before the first one.  If you want them to execute in the order they were requested, you would have to add code to enforce that by queuing later ones until the earlier ones completed.

Comment: Ok, now i'm clarified. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Genesis and Gaurav are right about disabling user interaction. +1 from me to each of them. How you handle the logic is actually quite simple:

```
$('#my_submit_button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'/my_file.php',
        dataType='json',
        beforeSend:function(){
            $('#my_submit_button').prop('disabled',true);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error){
            // handle status for each: "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror"
            // Show submit button again:
            $('#my_ajax_container').html('Oops we had a hiccup: ' + status);
            $('#my_submit_button').prop('disabled',false);
        },
        success:function(data){
            $('#my_ajax_container').html(data);
            $('#my_submit_button').prop('disabled',false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: But making it synchronous can make something bad happen. What if the call hangs for some reason?

Comment: Ajax by its very nature is asynchronous. That's what the `A` in `AJAX` stands for, you know ;) If you're worried about the response, you can (and should always) add error handling. See updated code.

Answer (score 1):

- make it synchronous (not recommended)
- disable link/button while ajaxing
- do not mind about it

but in your case it won't do any conflicts because when html is replaced, scripts too

Comment: Yes, that was my first tough, but then i see pages like facebook, i don't think that they make it synchronous. If i press the back button, then go forward and back again, or click on other link repeatedly, it does not appear that it loads all the content before it jumps to another call ...

Comment: What do you recommend then? can you point me some place to learn about effective ways to do this?

Comment: Ok, i see, thank you, to bad i can't rep+ you because i don't have enough rep to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the buttons that cause the AJAX calls to start while one has not completed yet.